# Spring Boot, logback and logging.config property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, logback

I am implementing logging in a Spring Boot project with *logback* library. I want to load different logging configuration files according to my Spring profiles (property `spring.pofiles.active`). I have 3 files:

- *logback-dev.xml*
- *logback-inte.xml*
- *logback-prod.xml*

I am using Spring Boot version 1.2.2.RELEASE.

---

As you can read in Spring Boot [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html):

> The various logging systems can be activated by including the appropriate libraries on the classpath, and further customized by providing a suitable configuration file in the root of the classpath, or in a location specified by the Spring Environment property **logging.config**. (Note however that since logging is initialized before the ApplicationContext is created, it isn’t possible to control logging from @PropertySources in Spring @Configuration files. System properties and the conventional Spring Boot external configuration files work just fine.)

So I tried to set `logging.config` property in my *application.properties* file:

```
logging.config=classpath:/logback-${spring.profiles.active}.xml
```

But when i start my application, my logback-{profile}.xml is not loaded.

I think logging is a common problem that all projects using Spring Boot have encountered. Am I on the right track with the above approach?

I have other solutions that work, but I find them not as elegant (conditional parsing with Janino in *logback.xml* file or command line property).

Comment: did you find an elegant solution for when you have multiple active profiles at the same time?

Comment: Check my edit on March 3 '2016

Comment: check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49568780/4369820

Comment: Find your answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54477155/5756557

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I found a solution and I understood why Spring doesn't use my `logging.config` property defined in the *application.properties* file.

## Solution and explanation

When initializing logging, Spring Boot only looks in [classpath or environment variables](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/0.5.0.M3/api/org/springframework/boot/context/initializer/LoggingApplicationContextInitializer.html).

The solution I used was to include a parent *logback.xml* file that included the right logging config file according to the Spring profile.

*logback.xml*

```xml
<configuration>
    <include resource="logback-${spring.profiles.active}.xml"/>
</configuration>
```

*logback-[profile].xml* (in this case, *logback-dev.xml*) :

```xml
<included>

    <!-- put your appenders -->
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
     ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
       <encoder>
           <pattern>%d{ISO8601} %p %t %c{0}.%M - %m%n</pattern>
           <charset>utf8</charset>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- put your loggers here -->
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" additivity="false" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </logger>

    <!-- put your root here -->
    <root level="warn">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>

</included>
```

#### Note

`spring.profiles.active` has to be set in command line arguments when starting the app.
Example for JVM properties: `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev`

---

### Reference documentation

- http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html
- http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html
- http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/0.5.0.M3/api/org/springframework/boot/context/initializer/LoggingApplicationContextInitializer.html

---

### Edit (multiple active profiles)

In order to avoid multiple files, we could use conditional processing which requires Janino dependency ([setup here](http://logback.qos.ch/setup.html#janino)), see [conditional documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#conditional).

With this method, we can also check for multiple *active profiles* at the same time. E.g (I did not test this solution, so please comment if it does not work):

```xml
<configuration>

    <if condition='"${spring.profiles.active}".contains("profile1")'>
        <then>
         <!-- do whatever you want for profile1 -->
        </then>
    </if>

    <if condition='"${spring.profiles.active}".contains("profile2")'>
        <then>
         <!-- do whatever you want for profile2 -->
        </then>
    </if>

    <!-- common config -->

</configuration>
```

See *@javasenior* [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35886713/814702) for another example of a conditional processing.

Comment: This approach seems good for your use case, however, we may have more than one profile defined in the environment which would cause the include to break. i.e. spring.profiles.active=profile1,profile2. <include resource="logback-profile1,profile2.xml"/>

Comment: Yes that's true. In this case i would use janino library.

Comment: any updates on an elegant solution for when you have multiple active profiles at the same time?

Comment: Checkout the [springProfile extension](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-logback-extensions) coming in Spring Boot 1.3.0

Comment: you can also define profile in application.properties with default dev as spring.profiles.active=${dev:dev}. If you don't pass -Dspring.profiles.active default will be dev

Comment: In case people still stumble on this issue: the actual cause is Tomcat overriding config.location. There's a fix for it in Tomcat 10.

Answer (score 47):

Another approach that could handle multiple profiles is to create a separate properties file for each environment.

application-prod.properties

```
logging.config=classpath:logback-prod.xml
```

application-dev.properties

```
logging.config=classpath:logback-dev.xml
```

application-local.properties

```
logging.config=classpath:logback-local.xml
```

**BE AWARE**

If you aren't careful you could end up logging somewhere unexpected

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=local,dev //will use logback-dev.xml
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev,local //will use logback-local.xml
```

Answer (score 11):

Instead of adding separate logback xmls for each profile or having the IF condition , I would suggest the following (If you have less difference in the xmls') for easy conditional processing
Documentation link [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging.logback-extensions.profile-specific):

```xml
<springProfile name="dev">
<logger name="org.sample" level="DEBUG" />
</springProfile>
<springProfile name="prod">
<logger name="org.sample" level="TRACE" />
</springProfile>
```

Comment: Link to the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#_profile_specific_configuration

Comment: we still have to specify spring.profiles.active=mode right ?

Answer (score 5):

Conditional processing with logback will be a solution without many logback files. Here is [a link](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#conditional) and a sample logback configuration with spring profiles.

```xml
<configuration>

    <property name="LOG_LEVEL" value="INFO"/>

        <if condition='"product".equals("${spring.profiles.active}")'>
           <then>
                <property name="LOG_LEVEL" value="INFO"/>
           </then>
           <else>
                <property name="LOG_LEVEL" value="ERROR"/>
           </else>
        </if>

         .
         .
         appender, logger tags etc.
         .
         .

         <root level="${LOG_LEVEL}">
             <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
         </root>

</configuration>
```

Also, you might have to add this to your pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
    <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can specific different logback.xml for different profile, only 3 steps:

1, Specify actived profile in `application.properties` or `application.yml`:

```
spring.profiles.active: test
```

2, Config logback to include different configuration by profile:

```
<!DOCTYPE configuration>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">
    <springProperty scope="context" name="profile" source="spring.profiles.active"/>
    <include resource="logback.${profile}.xml"/>
</configuration>
```

3, Create configuration file `logback.test.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<included>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <root level="INFO"/>
</included>
```

It's very simple, don't need do anything else.

Answer (score 4):

Spring has support of next tag `<springProperty/>` inside Logback XML file, this tag described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html) . It means that you can easily add variable from Spring property file, even this variable value resolves from environment/system variable by Spring.