# Spring boot logging

Tags: java, spring, logging, service, spring-boot

I am using Spring boot to build a simple REST service and I am wondering about the most appropriate way to handle the logging.

In my ***application.properties*** file I have the following:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG
```

While developing the application I simply run it as such:

```
java -jar myapp.war
```

thus, I got all the nice log messages in stdout. However, I intend to deploy it, and I'm wondering what is the most appropriate way to deploy the application and still have my logs.

Sure, one can simply redirect the output

```
java -jar myapp.war >> somefile
```

but this is not very elegant, and I want to deploy my application so that it can easily be used as a service:

```
ln -s /my/app/xyz.war /etc/init.d/xyz
```

Then, doing

```
service xyz start|stop|restrart
```

to manage it. Seems like doing this prevents me from redirecting stdout ..

Any ideas or advice about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you application.properties file you can set two attributes for your logging.file.

Like in the documentation description: ([26.3 File output](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html))

> By default, Spring Boot will only log to the console and will not
>   write log files. If you want to write log files in addition to the
>   console output you need to set a...

- `logging.file`

  > Writes to the specified log file. Names can be an exact location or relative to the current directory.
- `logging.path`

  > Writes spring.log to the specified directory. Names can be an exact location or relative to the current directory.

After setting one of those logging properties will be written in a file.

[Here you can find the complete doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html)

Answer (score 6):

What you are really after is Spring Boot [file logging output](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logging-file-output) functionality.

Quoting the above documentation:

> By default, Spring Boot will only log to the console and will not
>   write log files. If you want to write log files in addition to the
>   console output you need to set a logging.file or logging.path property
>   (for example in your application.properties).

Essentially adding in your `application.properties`:

```
logging.file=name.of.my.log.file.log
logging.path=/path/where/above/log/file/gets/stored
```

Answer (score 2):

I want to give a short **update in 2020**:

---

`logging.file` and `logging.path` are now *deprecated*:

[image: Screenshot of application.properties showing that logging.file and logging.path are deprecated]

---

Instead, I suggest to use **`logging.file.name`** in your **`application.properties`** (`logging.file.path` is also available).

Example: `logging.file.name=./logdir/spring.log`

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot support almost every logging frameworks you can use as per your convenience, but I will suggest you to use ***slf4j*** logging framework and customize using ***logback.xml*** it's very easy look at

1) Create LOGGER object adding this single line of code in your class

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(YourClassName.class);
```

2) Create logback.xml file in /resource folder and copy below code

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <appender name = "STDOUT" class = "ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
      <encoder>
         <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MMM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sss'Z'}] [%C] [%t] [%L] [%-5p] %m%n</pattern>
      </encoder>
   </appender>

   <appender name = "FILE" class = "ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
      <File>/var/tmp/app.log</File> <!-- LOCATION of FILE WHERE YOU WANT TO SAVE -->
      <encoder>
         <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sss'Z'}] [%C] [%t] [%L] [%-5p] %m%n</pattern>
      </encoder>
   </appender>

   <root level = "INFO">
      <appender-ref ref = "FILE"/>
      <appender-ref ref = "STDOUT"/> 
   </root>
</configuration>
```

Using **logback.xml** configuration you can customize your application logging in spring boot