# SpringBoot logback-spring.xml springprofile is not working

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-boot, logback

In my logback-spring.xml if I include logger level as INFO it is working fine but for other than INFO(WARN,ERROR) even application is not loading.After below log in console applicatiton booting is stopped forever.[This is the link we tried for this](https://springframework.guru/logback-configuration-using-xml/).Any help is appreciable.

**Output in Console as log:**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.2.RELEASE)
```

**logback-spring.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />
    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}-%msg %n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>TRACE</level>
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="minuteRollingFileAppender"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>/usr/src/app/logs/test%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm}.log
            </FileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{35}-%msg %n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>     


    <springProfile name="dev,staging"> 
        <root>
            <level value="INFO" /><!--ERROR not working -->
            <appender-ref ref="minuteRollingFileAppender" />
            <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
        </root>
    </springProfile>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429073/spring-boot-logback-and-logging-config-property)may help you

Comment: Thanks for reply,I will check.

Comment: is your application really dont loading? I think its a normal behavior that you only see the banner and than no other logs if the level is not INFO

Comment: @Patrick, Thanks I got it yes it is working as expected I wrongly checking something.

Comment: @sunleo had the same behavior some times ago. Good that the app is starting normally. Just created an answer for other users with the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spring-boot banner could be explicit included or excluded from the console. There are settings in some IDE's to do that.

If you dont have any logs for log level different than `INFO` you will only see the banner for application start. It looks like the application does not start but thats just because there are no logs written.

Excluding the banner in `application.properties`:

```
spring.main.banner-mode=off
```

or in `main`:

```
SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(SpringBootConsoleApplication.class);
app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
app.run(args);
```