# Spring Boot: Enable logging in file in production environment only

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging

I have this configuration in `application.properties`:

```
logging.config=classpath:logback.xml
logging.file=logfile.log
```

I have configued logback.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I want this logging functionality in production mode only

```
spring.profiles.active=pro
```

Is it possible i can configure `logging.***` properties programatically. so that i can enable it in production only not on development.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31631289/1299774) answer, perhaps this can help.

Comment: I have only one `application.properties` file . I don't want to split

Comment: `logback.xml` - it is default name and will be using in spring by default. In your case you should rename it for example: `logback-prod.xml` and change spring property to the `logging.config=classpath:logback-prod.xml`