# Spring Boot + Logback - external config vs local config

Tags: spring-boot, logback, properties-file

I have a Spring Boot app with a local application.properties file, containing among others:

```
logging.config=src/main/resources/local/logback-dev.xml
```

In this logback-dev.xml file, there is a file appender with a local path (say /local/path/log/)

When deploying to a different environment (say PROD), the guy who deploy uses his own application.properties file as externalized configuration (--spring.config.location=...), containing among others:

```
logging.config=/prod/path/logback-prod.xml
```

In that logback-prod.xml file, there is a file appender with a different path (say /prod/path/log/)

When running the application, an error rises, as it seems **both** files are utilized: we get in the log present in /prod/path/log/ messages such as "**cannot find path /local/path/log/**"

Could someone explain what's happening here? I thought the externalized config would override the local one, but something is odd here.

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot is this? Generally there is a main application.properties which is used for prod and an application-dev.properties where values are overridden. We can switch to the `-dev` profile by specifying `--spring.profiles.active=dev` at command line.

Comment: Spring Boot 2.0.3

Comment: Actually we do not have the required values for the PROD env., thus it has to come from an externalized configuration file. Would it mean that we do not need the application.properties since it will be provided later on? Or else a rather "empty" application.properties file (without PROD specific data for example)?
This issue actually came from a mistake, but it impacted the PROD env. and we do not exactly understand why, would be nice to know what happened

Comment: Are you sure you haven’t somehow packaged your local application.properties along with the fat jar?

Comment: yes it had been packaged actually, we thought it did not matter since it would be overriden anyway. Which works except for that logger...

Comment: See if this is related to your problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429073/spring-boot-logback-and-logging-config-property

Comment: Well, not really, more like a different way to do. My question is more on understanding what's going on with the properties overriding

Comment: Sadly no one seems to have actually answered your question, just provided workarounds, @khalil-bouzekri. I want to look at externalizing my logback config so I'll see if I experience the same behaviour and, if so, what explains it and what that means for solving it.

Answer (score 1):

We have the same problem and have found a solution with the help of this documentation:
**External Configuration** 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config
**Application Properties**
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files

In Pom we added:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/application.properties</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/application-development.properties</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/application-production.properties</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/logback.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Hope this will solve your problem and helping to understand.

Comment: Thanks for your proposition. However it seems that this would only work if there is always an externalized configuration. In my case it might not be the case (sometimes the local one should be used, but in the case of an externalized one, that one should be taken into account), as unfortunately we do not have a say on the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, putting `logging.config` in your `application.properties` or on the command line as an application option (`--logging.config`) has no effect. It looks like processing of those properties happens *after* logging has already been initialized, so any properties defined in it would be added to the environment too late.

Which makes you wonder why they even have the `logging.config` property. I'll need to dig into that a bit more :-)

What does work:
Use the native Logback way of specifying a config file by setting the system property `logback.configurationFile`, e.g. by passing `-Dlogback.configurationFile` on the `java` command line *before the `-jar` or `mainclass` argument*. You can pass a different file name here depending on the environment (dev, prod) you're running in. If you omit it, Spring will end up finding the `logback.xml` on your classpath (from `src/main/resources` in your source code) which sounds like the default you want.