# Spring boot logging.file ignored, taking logback-test.xml from classpath

Tags: java, spring-boot, slf4j

When we deployed our spring boot 2.7 app to the production, it has troubles reading a correct log configuration. Instead of using a config file set in the prod profile it selects a test related resource from class path.

```
$ java -Dspring.profiles.active=prod service.jar
service.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/logback-test.xml]
12:13:29,834 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@23ab930d - URL [jar:file:/home/x/service.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/logback-test.xml] is not of type file
12:13:29,865 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
```

**application-prod.yml**

```
logging:
  config: /home/x/service/config/logback-prod.xml
```

The jar contains these files in classpath (log4j should not be there, we removed this dependency, and we are relying on default SLF4J):

```
$ ls log*
log4j2.xml log4j2-prod.xml log4j2-test.xml logback.xml logback-prod.xml logback-test.xml
```

Application is using the prod profile except `logging.config` option. Why?

Comment: Spring boot 2.7 documentation:
logging.file.path LOG_PATH If defined, it is used in the default log configuration.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.0/reference/htmlsingle/#features.logging

Comment: So it seems that the property has changed, and developer was looking to the old documentation.

Comment: I tried to pass logging.file.path as a system property or capitalized env variable without any luck.

Comment: Spring will search (when running, not when building the jar) the logging config on /home/x/service/config/logback-prod.xml : does this file exists on the specified path?

Comment: Looks like there was similar problem, take a look to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429073/spring-boot-logback-and-logging-config-property

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to remove the log configuration files from the build, because they were always read by Spring.

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>log*xml</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Comment: Which file is this in? pom.xml?

Comment: Yes, under the build element.